# Qual a maneira certa ou como fechar conexoẽs persistentes do PDO no PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, conexão

Preciso fechar a conexão com o banco MySQL no PHP no código abaixo:

```
try {
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=banco', "root", "", array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
//tenta fechar a conexao
$conn = null;
```

Eu preciso fechar a conexão persistente com um banco MySQL no PHP. Eu tentei fechar a conexão setando a variavel `$conn` como `null`, mas não parece que esteja dando certo.

Quando uso o comando `SHOW STATUS WHERE` variable_name `= 'Threads_connected';` no MySQL para verificar as conexões ativas elas não diminuem, porém funcionam quando a conexão não é persistente e seto a variavel `$conn` como `null`.

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: `$conn = null;` isso está correto, mas uma conexão persistente assim como pools não fecham de imediato quando destroi o objeto, se quer a conexão fechando quando destruir o objeto não use uma conexão persistente

Answer (score 2):

Respondendo sua pergunta, segunda a documentação aqui: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

> Persistent connections are not closed at the end of the script, but
> are cached and re-used when another script requests a connection using
> the same credentials. The persistent connection cache allows you to
> avoid the overhead of establishing a new connection every time a
> script needs to talk to a database, resulting in a faster web
> application.

Ou seja, *"Conexões persistentes não são fechadas ao final do script, elas ficam em cache para ser reutilizadas"*.

Ao setar o objeto conexão com null (`$conn = null`) libera o objeto para ser destruido e a conexão para ser fechada. Se quer a conexão fechada nesse ponto, não use uma conexão persistente, pois isso é exatamente o contrário do seu propósito.

O propósito de uma conexão persistente é permanecer aberta para evitar o *overhead* de refazer a conexão.

Comment: agradeço pela resposta, mas então não faz sentido eu fechar a conexão persistente? porem o banco do projeto que estou dando manutenção esta sendo sobrecarregado de conexões, me tire outra duvida, se eu criar 2 conexões persistentes seguidas ou mais elas serão as mesmas? e se forem ou se não forem fechar essas conexões vai mudar algo em ambos os casos?

Comment: Eu particularmente preferiro outro recurso que é o *pooling* de conexões, mas isso depende do driver que está usando para se conectar. A vantagem do polling é que eu posso configurar por exemplo "mater o mínimo de 2 conexões abertas, e se necessário abrir no máximo 10", mas se preferir usar as conexões persistentes, ou até se o driver não permitir, pode limitar o número de conexões abertas pela `mysql`, no "my.ini". Sobre as conexões, não deveria criar multiplas, conforme a documentação *"re-used when another script requests a connection using the same credentials"* se usar a mesma credential